# htaccess redirect invoice.php to /client/invoice.php

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I am looking at installing Wordpress into my WHMCS website and I would like to make it so any old invoices or support tickets go to the new subfolder.

Current links will look like this

```
https://www.example.com/viewinvoice.php?id=15515
https://www.example.com/viewticket.php?tid=955170&c=j3122yq7
```

What should I put in `.htaccess` so anyone who goes to those links will be redirected to:

```
https://www.example.com/client/viewinvoice.php?id=15515
https://www.example.com/client/viewticket.php?tid=955170&c=j3122yq7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you just want to inject a `/client` subdirectory, for specific URLs, from the document root. You can do this using mod_rewrite, at the top of your `.htaccess` file (*before* the WordPress front-controller). For example:

```
RewriteRule ^view(invoice|ticket)\.php$ /client/$0 [R=302,L]
```

This will redirect either `/viewinvoice.php` or `/viewticket.php` to `/client/viewinvoice.php` and `/client/viewticket.php` respectively. The query string is passed through to the target unaltered.

The `$0` backreference in the *substitution* refers to the URL-path that matches the entire `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

Note that this is currently a *temporary* (302) redirect. Change the 302 to 301 if this is intended to be permanent, but only once you have confirmed it works OK (to avoid caching issues). Make sure your browser cache is cleared before testing.